# VBA code to Autofill a variable number of Columns

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I'm new to using VBA, I understand how to autofill a predefined number of columns/rows, however, I'd like the user to be able to input a number into a cell, and starting with a static column/row, the code autofills however many columns the user wants(in this instance how many pay periods an employee would work.) This is what I have so far.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AutoFill_Test()
'A1 here being where the total number of payperiods are found

Range("A1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:D2"), Type:=xlFillCopy

End Sub
```

How would I modify this to achieve the desired result?
many thanks,

Comment: You'd need to use `Application.InputBox`.

Comment: There isn't anyway to have the user fill in each row in a particular column with values, and use one consolidated button to output the rows? There are a lot of employees and the input box wouldn't be ideal for workflow.

Comment: That is also an option, yes.